# XPath in R: selecting values

Tags: xml, r, xpath, bioinformatics

I have an XML file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE pathway SYSTEM "http://www.kegg.jp/kegg/xml/KGML_v0.7.1_.dtd">
<!-- Creation date: Sep 1, 2014 12:00:13 +0900 (GMT+09:00) -->
<pathway name="path:hsa04010" org="hsa" number="04010"
         title="MAPK signaling pathway"
         image="http://www.kegg.jp/kegg/pathway/hsa/hsa04010.png"
         link="http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?hsa04010">
    <entry id="1" name="cpd:C00338" type="compound"
        link="http://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?C00338">
        <graphics name="C00338" fgcolor="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"
             type="circle" x="138" y="743" width="8" height="8"/>
    </entry>
    <entry id="2" name="hsa:5923 hsa:5924" type="gene"
        link="http://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?hsa:5923+hsa:5924">
        <graphics name="RASGRF1, CDC25, CDC25L, GNRP, GRF1, GRF55, H-GRF55, PP13187, ras-GRF1..." fgcolor="#000000" bgcolor="#BFFFBF"
             type="rectangle" x="392" y="236" width="46" height="17"/>
    <relation entry1="47" entry2="40" type="PPrel">
        <subtype name="activation" value="--&gt;"/>
    </relation>
    <relation entry1="46" entry2="40" type="PPrel">
        <subtype name="activation" value="--&gt;"/>
    </relation>
    <relation entry1="45" entry2="40" type="PPrel">
        <subtype name="activation" value="--&gt;"/>
    </relation>
```

What I would like to do is this:

1. Extract all the `id` and `name` attributes of the `entry` children that have `type="gene"` and store them in a list/dictionary/dataframe for later use.
2. Extract all the attributes of the `relation` children and store them in a similar structure.

I've just started with XML parsing, and I've been trying to read other questions here in Stackoverflow as well as various FAQs around the web, but I can't seem to get it to work. I can do the following and select all the nodes according to (1) above:

```
data = xmlTreeParse('~/Downloads/hsa04010.xml')
root = xmlRoot(data)
getNodeSet(root, '/pathway/entry[@type="gene"]')
```

... which works correctly, but I don't know how to get the two separate values (all of them in the second case) and store them somewhere. I tried

```
getNodeSet(root, '/pathway/entry[@type="gene"]/@id')
```

... but that only gives me an error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
      unable to find an inherited method for function ‘saveXML’ for signature ‘"XMLAttributeValue"’
```

Even if it'd work I'd only get the `id` attribute, and not `name` as well, which I would like. But seeing as I can't seem to be able to get even just a single attribute value, well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a KGML parser in the [KEGGgraph](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/KEGGgraph.html) package that may help.  Check the vignette for details

```
library(KEGGgraph)
url <- "http://rest.kegg.jp/get/hsa04010/kgml"
x <- parseKGML(url)
```

You can also parse the url directly and then use different xpath queries suggested here or something like xmlAttrsToDataFrame that's explained in the new XML for data sciences in R book.

```
doc <- xmlParse(url)
genes <- XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(doc["//entry[@type='gene']"])

relations <- XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(doc["//relation"])
relations
    entry1 entry2  type
1       47     40 PPrel
2       46     40 PPrel
3       45     40 PPrel
4       44     39 PPrel
5       43     38 PPrel
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your second way of doing it with the XPath queries worked! The KEGGgraph package seems nice, but I'd prefer to learn a general XML solution, so the `xmlAttrsToDataFrame` worked great!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
lapply(data['/pathway/entry[@type="gene"]/@id | /pathway/entry[@type="gene"]/*//@name'], as, "character")
# [[1]]
# [1] "2"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "RASGRF1, CDC25, CDC25L, GNRP, GRF1, GRF55, H-GRF55, PP13187, ras-GRF1..."
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "activation"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "activation"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "activation"
```

and

```
xpathApply(data, '/pathway/entry[@type="gene"]//relation', xmlAttrs)
# [[1]]
# entry1  entry2    type 
# "47"    "40" "PPrel" 
# 
# [[2]]
# entry1  entry2    type 
# "46"    "40" "PPrel" 
# 
# [[3]]
# entry1  entry2    type 
# "45"    "40" "PPrel
```

### Edit:

`data` is

```
data <-  xmlParse('<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE pathway SYSTEM "http://www.kegg.jp/kegg/xml/KGML_v0.7.1_.dtd">
  <!-- Creation date: Sep 1, 2014 12:00:13 +0900 (GMT+09:00) -->
  <pathway name="path:hsa04010" org="hsa" number="04010"
title="MAPK signaling pathway"
image="http://www.kegg.jp/kegg/pathway/hsa/hsa04010.png"
link="http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?hsa04010">
  <entry id="1" name="cpd:C00338" type="compound"
link="http://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?C00338">
  <graphics name="C00338" fgcolor="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"
type="circle" x="138" y="743" width="8" height="8"/>
  </entry>
  <entry id="2" name="hsa:5923 hsa:5924" type="gene"
link="http://www.kegg.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?hsa:5923+hsa:5924">
  <graphics name="RASGRF1, CDC25, CDC25L, GNRP, GRF1, GRF55, H-GRF55, PP13187, ras-GRF1..." fgcolor="#000000" bgcolor="#BFFFBF"
type="rectangle" x="392" y="236" width="46" height="17"/>
  <relation entry1="47" entry2="40" type="PPrel">
  <subtype name="activation" value="--&gt;"/>
  </relation>
  <relation entry1="46" entry2="40" type="PPrel">
  <subtype name="activation" value="--&gt;"/>
  </relation>
  <relation entry1="45" entry2="40" type="PPrel">
  <subtype name="activation" value="--&gt;"/>
  </relation>
</entry>
</pathway>', asText = TRUE)
```

Comment: I don't seem to get the same results... `> lapply(data['/pathway/entry[@type="gene"]/@id | /pathway/entry[@type="gene"]/*//@name'], as, .... [TRUNCATED]; $<NA>; character(0)` is what I get in the first case, and just `list()` for the `xpathApply(root, '/pathway/entry[@type="gene"]//relation', xmlAttrs)`... Did I do something wrong? I just copy-pasted it from your post.

Comment: Hm but I wrote `xpathApply(data, '/pathway/entry[@type="gene"]//relation', xmlAttrs)` and not `xpathApply(root, '/pathway/entry[@type="gene"]//relation', xmlAttrs)`. :-> Anyway, I added the variable `data`, which I used.

Comment: Ah, okey, so it's to do with how I read the file! I have `data = xmlTreeParse('~/Downloads/hsa04010.xml')`, how should I change that to work with your code? I assume I use `xmlParse` and `asText=TRUE` rather than `xmlTreeParse`, but giving the path to my file just gives me `does not seem to be xml`...

Comment: `xmlParse` is like `xmlTreeParse(..., useInternalNodes = TRUE)`. I added `</entry>
</pathway>` to your example to be able to read the xml. `data = xmlParse('~/Downloads/hsa04010.xml', useInternalNodes = TRUE)` is not working?

Comment: This is what I have now: `data = xmlParse('~/Downloads/hsa04010.xml', useInternalNodes = TRUE)`; `xpathApply(data, '/pathway/entry[@type="gene"]//relation', xmlAttrs)`, and from that I just get `list()` as some kind of result, and I don't know why that is =/

Comment: Well, as I don't have hsa04010.xml I cannot reproduce the problem, sorry.